# How does the iframe border affect iframe size, and where is it specified?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I found that some media queries I had running on an iframe were not working. 
The iframe size is 1280px w by 730px h

The media query is stylesheet

```
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1280px)
```

And the border of the iframe is 1px in size. 
so if I do

```
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1279px)
```

instead, it works.

I am checking this in Firefox in Mac OS X, there is no viewport set in the html but I suppose it shouldn't affect it in this case.

So what I want to know is, is this behaviour as specified and if so can you point me to the relevant part of the spec, if it is a particular browser quirk can you point me to a list of how border size affects Iframe width in calculation of min-width for the window.

This was edited from when I didn't know what was causing the media query to fail.

Comment: could it be that the iframe borders cut off a bit of the width? did you test which width your document has (via javascript)?

Comment: ok I'll try checking to see the width, but according to the markup <iframe id="target_iframe" src="about:blank" name="target_iframe" style="width: 1280px; height: 738px;">

Comment: You were right, it seems that in firefox at least the iframe border - being 1px, affects the actual window size of the iframe. I had expected the border was exterior to the document inside the iframe, so that the 1px border did not take off 1px from the available width.